# Cannot solve the 'Model cannot be overwritten once complied' error on mongoose

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

**Problem**: So I'm trying to integrate MongoDB into my nextJs project. Here's a library file which connects to the database.

```js
import shopSchema from './Schemas/shopSchema';
let shopModelCached;
async function getShopModel(connectionUrl) {
  if (!shopModelCached) {
    try {
      await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_DB_CONNECTION_STRING);
      const Shop = mongoose.model("shop", shopSchema);
      shopModelCached = Shop;
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  return shopModelCached;
}

export default getShopModel;
```

When I call the function to get the shop model on my `getServerSidedProps` on my page, which does literally nothing but call the above function to get the `Shop` model, and then performs simple query to populate the props.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  try {
    const Shop = await getShopModel(
      process.env.MONGO_DB_CONNECTION_STRING
    );
    const shop = await Shop.findOne({
      shopcode: context.params.shopname,
    }).exec();
    return {
      props: {
        shop,
      },
    };
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
}
```

This hits me with an error when I recompile modules. It says, `'OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite 'shop' model once compiled.'.` My approach to handling this was to cache the model so it wouldn't be overwritten, but to no vain.

Comment: Why are you calling your db connection `Shop`?

Comment: @GabrielLupu I only need one connection. So better to get the model on connecting to the DB.